# Undecorating the C++ symbols on Windows

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, linker-errors, name-mangling

I want to know the undecorated name of symbol "_DirectInput8Create@20" which i am getting as linker error

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DirectInput8Create@20 referenced

I tried using undname but i am not getting the expected result. It prints the same symbol as its output as shown below

```
undname.exe _DirectInput8Create@20
Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Undecoration of :- "_DirectInput8Create@20"

is :- "_DirectInput8Create@20"
```

Comment: Also, be sure to not use legacy DirectInput for keyboard or mouse. It's main use today is for accessing HID-based controllers and joysticks, and the keyboard/mouse stuff is a pile of hacks.

Comment: Undname.exe only undecorates names that were mangled by the C++ compiler.  This C linkage symbol has simple __stdcall decoration, drop the leading underscore and the @xx suffix.